# Error changing layout mode from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: android-layout

I'm getting error from changing layout mode from changing layout mode in android..

I have an activity that has a onCreate code here..

```
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_chart_area, null);
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.chart_area);
    TextView textTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_title_chart_area);
    textTitle.setText(titleChart);
    View i = chart;
    if (chart instanceof ImageView) {
        l.addView(i, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    } else {
        l.addView(i);
    }
    setContentView(v);
```

I have inflated it, I have already try using setContentView directly but the result the same it has return error below code :

```
          06-29 11:23:22.413: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8182): Caused by:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

My xml layout are here:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" android:text="Judul dari Chart yang akan ditampilkan"
        android:id="@+id/text_title_chart_area" android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/chart_area"> 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that your `chart` view is persisting for longer than your Activity, and is therefore being added to a parent multiple times without being removed when the parent is destroyed. It's difficult to be certain without seeing more of your code.

You could try adding an `onDestroy()` method which removes it:

```
@Override
void onDestroy()
{
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chart_area)).removeView( chart );
}
```

Alternatively, you could try instantiating a new `chart` in `onCreate()`.